# how to redirect link 404 error with content symbol url

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, http-status-code-301

I couldn't find a straight answer to my question and need to know it from the real experts.
I have a link
1)

```
http://www.example.com/example.html%20text-decoration:%20none%E2%80%9D%3Eexample.com%3C%20%3C/i%3E%3C/span%3E%3Cbr%3E%3Cbr%3E%3Cbr%3E%3Ctable%20bgcolor=
```

2)

```
http://www.example.com/examindex/?p=2343543
```

My question, how can I redirect link 301 with a .htaccess file?
i want to redirect 301 link 1 to http://www.example.com/example.html

```
redirect 301 /example.html%20text-decoration:%20none%E2%80%9D%3Eexample.com%3C%20%3C/i%3E%3C/span%3E%3Cbr%3E%3Cbr%3E%3Cbr%3E%3Ctable%20bgcolor= http://www.example.com/example.html
```

link 2 to http://www.example.com/examindex/

```
redirect 301 /examindex/?p=2343543 http://www.example.com/examindex/
```

but it's not working.
Can anyone help me please?
Thank you so much,

Comment: Don't you actually need status 410 (Gone) instead of 301 (Moved)? Because it seems to me that the page `?p=2343543` does not exists anymore in your case, it is not replaced with the index page.

Comment: yes, i want to redirect 301 link http://www.example.com/examindex/?p=2343543 to http://www.example.com/examindex/ . because link http://www.example.com/examindex/?p=2343543 does not exists. it's is a post but i deleted it.

Comment: Moved is not the same as deleted.

Comment: post in wordpress, i deleted it. but when i check link 404, it's appear here

Comment: Please don't double post. This question has already been answered on Pro Webmasters: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/77257/how-to-redirect-link-404-error-with-content-symbol-url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use these 2 rules in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(example\.html)\x20 /$1 [L,NC,R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)p=2343543(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(examindex)/?$ /$1/? [L,NC,R=301]
```